# Apache Pig: Facing issue while handling datatype in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have been facing issue while handling the datatype for field `qty` and doing a `SUM` on the same field. Below is the code. I converted the `qty` to `double` but still getting the error mentioned below. Can someone please help me to understand this issue and if possible a solution?

```
A_test1 = load'EXT_OO_IMP' USING PigStorage('\u0001') AS (it: chararray,loc: chararray,qty: chararray,scheddate: chararray,udc_cta_no: chararray,udc_imp_pack_qty: chararray,udc_imp_ready_dt: chararray,udc_imp_ref_no: chararray,udc_ord_sys_cd: chararray,udc_source: chararray,udc_sply_typ: chararray,udc_vend_pack_id: chararray,udc_purch_stg: chararray,srs_pack_flow_indicator_cd: chararray,it_type_cd: chararray,source_owner_cd: chararray,nks_id: chararray,alloc_replen_cd: chararray);

----- ext_oo_import: {it: chararray,loc: chararray,qty: chararray,scheddate: chararray,udc_cta_no: chararray,udc_imp_pack_qty: chararray,udc_imp_ready_dt: chararray,udc_imp_ref_no: chararray,udc_ord_sys_cd: chararray,udc_source: chararray,udc_sply_typ: chararray,udc_vend_pack_id: chararray,udc_purch_stg: chararray,srs_pack_flow_indicator_cd: chararray,it_type_cd: chararray,source_owner_cd: chararray,nks_id: chararray,alloc_replen_cd: chararray}

----- ##############  ##############  ##############

import_on_order = 
        FOREACH A_test1
        GENERATE
            loc,
            it,
            nks_id,
            (double)(qty is NULL ? 0 : qty) as qty:double,
            scheddate,
            ' ' AS order_source,
            ' ' AS chs_it_type_cd;

describe import_on_order;

----- import_on_order: {loc: chararray,it: chararray,nks_id: chararray,qty: int,scheddate: chararray,order_source: chararray,chs_it_type_cd: chararray}


grp_import_on_order = GROUP import_on_order BY (loc,it,nks_id,scheddate,order_source,chs_it_type_cd);


describe grp_import_on_order;

----- grp_import_on_order: {group: (loc: chararray,it: chararray,nks_id: chararray,scheddate: chararray,order_source: chararray,chs_it_type_cd: chararray),import_on_order: {(loc: chararray,it: chararray,nks_id: chararray,qty: int,scheddate: chararray,order_source: chararray,chs_it_type_cd: chararray)}}



------------------------------- STORE TO FILE ---------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

work__idrp_import_on_order =
                            FOREACH grp_import_on_order 
                            GENERATE    group.loc AS loc,
                                        group.it AS it,
                                        group.nks_id AS nks_id,
                                        SUM(import_on_order.qty) AS qty,
                                        group.scheddate AS scheddate,
                                        group.order_source AS order_source,
                                        group.chs_it_type_cd AS chs_it_type_cd;

describe work__idrp_import_on_order;

----- work__idrp_import_on_order: {loc: chararray,it: chararray,nks_id: chararray,qty: int,scheddate: chararray,order_source: chararray,chs_it_type_cd: chararray}

import_on_order_rp = 
        FOREACH ext_oo_import
        GENERATE
            it AS chs_it,
            loc AS chs_loc,
            (qty is NULL ? 0 : qty) as qty:double,
            scheddate AS current_due_dt, 
            ' ' AS order_source,
            'V' AS source_type_cd,
            udc_sply_typ AS sply_typ,
            udc_ord_sys_cd AS ord_sys_cd;
```

> 2019-01-31 09:03:30,819 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: grp_import_on_order: Local Rearrange[tuple]{tuple}(false) - scope-1095 Operator Key: scope-1095): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: work__idrp_import_on_order: New For Each(false,false)[bag] - scope-1078 Operator Key: scope-1078): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: Pre Combiner Local Rearrange[tuple]{Unknown} - scope-1097 Operator Key: scope-1097): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: import_on_order: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-977 Operator Key: scope-977): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: ext_oo_import: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-957 Operator Key: scope-957): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-945 Operator Key: scope-945): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POCast (Name: Cast[double] - scope-926 Operator Key: scope-926) children: [[POProject (Name: Project[chararray][2] - scope-925 Operator Key: scope-925) children: null at []]] at []]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>   Details at logfile: /logs/hdidrp/pig/pig_1548942743751.log
>   2019-01-31 09:03:30,849 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
>   2019-01-31 09:03:31,012 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_DOUBLE 1 time(s).
>   import_on_order_rp: {shc_item: chararray,shc_loc: chararray,qty: double,current_due_dt: chararray,order_source: chararray,source_type_cd: chararray,sply_typ: chararray,ord_sys_cd: chararray}
>   2019-01-31 09:03:31,179 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: grp_import_on_order: Local Rearrange[tuple]{tuple}(false) - scope-1095 Operator Key: scope-1095): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: work__idrp_import_on_order: New For Each(false,false)[bag] - scope-1078 Operator Key: scope-1078): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: Pre Combiner Local Rearrange[tuple]{Unknown} - scope-1097 Operator Key: scope-1097): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: import_on_order: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-977 Operator Key: scope-977): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: ext_oo_import: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-957 Operator Key: scope-957): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false)[bag] - scope-945 Operator Key: scope-945): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POCast (Name: Cast[double] - scope-926 Operator Key: scope-926) children: [[POProject (Name: Project[chararray][2] - scope-925 Operator Key: scope-925) children: null at []]] at []]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

After looking at code, unable to get in first statement you are loading data and doing steps of transformation but again in last statament why you are transforming first data set again which is of string type and while working on this it giving exception.

> import_on_order_rp = FOREACH **ext_oo_import** GENERATE it AS chs_it, loc
>   AS chs_loc, (qty is NULL ? 0 : qty) as qty:double, scheddate AS
>   current_due_dt, ' ' AS order_source, 'V' AS source_type_cd,
>   udc_sply_typ AS sply_typ, udc_ord_sys_cd AS ord_sys_cd;

See if that is the correct case.

Comment: [[POProject (Name: Project[chararray][2] - scope-925 Operator Key: scope-925) children: null at []]] at []]: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: There are some null values in my data and i am trying to identify them and assign them a '0' as below:
import_on_order =
                FOREACH A_test1
                GENERATE
                        loc,
                        item,
                        ksn_id,
   (double)(qty is NULL ? '0' : qty) as qty:double,
                        /*(IsNull(qty,'') !='' ? qty : 0) as qty:long,*/
                        scheddate,
                        ' ' AS order_source,
                        ' ' AS shc_item_type_cd;

Comment: Can you take a look at this and help?